# Strange shadows on a blender model with subdivision surface

Tags: java, shadow, jmonkeyengine

Placing a blender model in the scene with shadows applied produces the following result.
[image: shadows on blender model]

The filters used are a `DirectionalLightShadowFilter`, `SSAOFilter` and `BloomFilter`. The model is exported using the OgreXML exporter. The strange thing is that the model doesn't have these strange shadows when not using a SubdivisonSurface in Blender. Is this a common problem with jme3 or could it be a Blender-related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is called [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).
It is due to two faces directly in the same position, "fight" about which face is shown an which stays hidden.

As a solution I would suggest changing to a person who is better at 3D-modelling than your current 3D Modelling guy.
This guy must be a real mess. Not that it was me or something.

No, seriously, this looks like it was designed with blender.
Here a solution would be this:

- Join the objects into one object / mesh (select all cubes in Object Mode, <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>)
- Enter editmode, select all <kbd>A</kbd> (if not already) and Remove Doubles (in <kbd>W</kbd> menu)